# Multiple definition of base class constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm creating some classes to encapsulate socket IO. I've created a base class to abstract out common data (file descriptors, port #s, etc) and functionality (most of the initialization). I have code that looks like this -
base.hpp

```
class Base { 
    protected:
        Base(int port);
        ~Base();
        // common data
};
Also here I have the implementations of the constructor and destructor
```

client.hpp

```
#include base.hpp
class Client : private Base {
    // constructor and other required code
}
```

testclient.cpp

```
#include "client.cpp"
int main() {
    Client c (ip, port);
    ... more stuff
    return 0;
}
```

I also have the implementation of the client class in client.cpp, and its constructor calls the base constructor appropriately. I also have correct and unique header guards. However, when linking client.o with testclient, I get linker errors citing multiple definitions of the Base constructor and destructor. What am I doing wrong? I would include the code, but it is quite long and I am convinced my error is due to some #include/linking magic.

Comment: Are you defining your constructor and destructor *outside* the class definition but still in the header, without `inline`? Because that's a paddlin'.

Comment: Does base.hpp have header guards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the functions are implemented in the header file you have to declare the definitions of the functions with `inline` to prevent having multiple definitions of the functions.

To fix the errors put `inline` in front of the implementations. For example for the constructor of `Base` do

```
inline Base::Base(int port)
^^^^^^ Difference here
{
    // Implementation
}
```

You can also have the implementation of the methods in the class as well.

`inline` informs the compiler that the function can be compiled in multiple .cpp files (functions declared inside the class definition are implicitly declared `inline`.) If the function is not declared as `inline` it is exported from each .cpp file. When the linker comes along, after the program is compiled, there is a definition of the function in each .cpp file that included the header. This causes the linker to give an error.

Comment: Marking the function with inline tells the compiler that it will be compiled in multiple translation units (a.k.a .cpp files). If you don't the linker will complain because it sees a definition for the function in multiple places.

Comment: Yes. The header file is pasted into the .cpp file before compilation. That is what the include directive does. Because you included client.h in testclient.cpp and client.cpp the function was defined in client.cpp and in testclient.cpp, which don't know about each other until the linker stage. There are then two definitions in the program, which makes the linker complain.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1:

In your header file `client.hpp`:

```
class Base { 
    protected:
        Base(int port) {
           ...
        }

        ~Base() {
           ...
        }
};
```

#### Option 2:

In your header file `client.hpp`:

```
class Base { 
    protected:
        Base(int port);
        ~Base();
};
```

And in your source file `client.cpp`:

```
Base::Base(int port) {
   ...
}

Base::~Base() {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#include base.hpp` should be this `#include "base.hpp"`
or `#include "base.h"`